# Does App Store accepts Custom Browser?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

am newbie to iOS developement.
I am creating a custom browser with typical browser functionalities like history,bookmarks and other custom options.

I want to know whether Apple pass the app or it will reject ?

Comment: Ask Apple, they will decide if or if not applicable for the AppStore.

Comment: eh there is a chrome app ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, App store accepts custom browsers, if you develop them according to App store guide line.

There are some browser apps like **'Chrome', 'Firefox', 'Opera Mini', 'Dolphin', 'Mercury', 'Puffin Browser'** present in app store.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a rule against web browsers in the app store. For example, [Google Chrome](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chrome-web-browser-by-google/id535886823?mt=8).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a custom rendering engine you will be rejected, but if you stick to `WebKit` you will be fine. Of course, you will need to adhere to HIG, ensure that there are no prominent bugs, etc.